# How can I create instances of a class with data from a nested array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, class, object, nested

I am creating a project where I have scraped data from a webpage for product info. 
My scraping method returns a nested array with a collection of product_names, urls, and prices. I'm trying to use the nested array to create instances of my class Supplies, with attributes of a name, url, and price. The nested array has the same number of elements in each of the 3 array.

I want to @@all to return an array of instances of all products in the collection with their attributes set.

```
name_url_price = [[],[],[]]

class Catalog::Supplies
  attr_accessor :name, :price, :url

  @@all = []

  def initialize(name_url_price)
    count = 0
    while count <= name_url_price[0].length
    self.name = name_url_price[0][count]
    self.url = name_url_price[1][count]
    self.price = name_url_price[2][count]
    @@all << self
    count += 1
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going wrong here but nothing that can't be fixed:

1. Storing all the instances in a class variable is a little strange. Creating the instances and having the caller track them would be more common and less confusing.
2. Your `while count <= ...` loop isn't terminated with an `end`.
3. Your loop condition looks wrong, `name_url_price[0]` is the first element of `name_url_price` so `name_url_price[0].length` will, presumably, always be three. If `name_url_price` looks more like `[ [names], [urls], [prices] ]` then the condition is right but that's a strange and confusing way to store your data.
4. `while` loops for iteration are very rare in Ruby, you'd normally use `name_url_place.each do ... end` or something from `Enumerable`.
5. Your array indexing is possibly backwards, you want to say `name_url_price[count][0]`, `name_url_price[count][1]`, ... But see **(3)** if I'm misunderstanding how your data is structured.
6. Your `@@all << self` is simply appending the same object (`self`) to `@@all` over and over again. `@@all` will end up with multiple references to the same object and that object's attributes will match the last iteration of the `while` loop.
7. The `initialize` method is meant to initialize a single instance, having it create a bunch of instances is very strange and confusing.

It would be more common and generally understandable for your class to look like this:

```
class Catalog::Supplies
  attr_accessor :name, :price, :url

  def initialize(name, url, price)
    self.name  = name
    self.url   = url
    self.price = price
  end
end
```

And then your `name_url_price` array would look more like this:

```
name_url_price = [
  [ 'name1', 'url1', 1 ],
  [ 'name2', 'url2', 2 ],
  [ 'name3', 'url3', 3 ],
  [ 'name4', 'url4', 4 ]
]
```

and to get the supplies as objects, whatever wanted the list would say:

```
supplies = name_url_price.map { |a| Catalog::Supplies.new(*a) }
```

You could also use hashes in `name_url_price`:

```
name_url_price = [
  { name: 'name1', url: 'url1', price: 1 },
  { name: 'name2', url: 'url2', price: 2 },
  { name: 'name3', url: 'url3', price: 3 },
  { name: 'name4', url: 'url4', price: 4 }
]
```

and then create your instances like this:

```
supplies = name_url_price.map do |h|
  Catalog::Supplies.new(
    h[:name],
    h[:url],
    h[:price]
  )
end
```

or like this:

```
supplies = name_url_price.map { |h| Catalog::Supplies.new(*h.values_at(:name, :url, :price)) }
```